# Node mssql server looping over and inserting

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js

Hi there I am using the mssql package and i have it working for one insert, but when I  am trying to insert after each loop it breaks or doesn't insert anything. It seems to work up to the point of the insert connection. I have tried putting it into a separate function but that doesn't work either. Anyone else try something like this. maybe a global connection, but not sure how to use it.

```
        dbconfigDemo = {
            server: "IP HERE",
            database: "DB",
            user: "Username",
            password: "passwordhere",
            port: 1433,

        }

            // Problems Section
            for (i = 0; i < ccda.data.problems.length; i++) {
            //loop each problem
                Problems = ccda.data.problems[i];

                var connection = new sql.Connection(dbconfigDemo, function(err) {
                var request = new sql.Request(connection); 

                 //Set variables here to use in insert   
                DOCUMENT_OID = Problems.age;
                PROBLEM_DOCUMENT_EXTENSION_ID = Problems.name;

              ");

                    request.query("INSERT INTO PROBLEM (DOCUMENT_OID,PROBLEM_DOCUMENT_EXTENSION_ID)" +
                    "VALUES (" +
                    "'" + DOCUMENT_OID + "'," +
                    "'" + PROBLEM_DOCUMENT_EXTENSION_ID + "'," +

                    });
                    //close the connection
                    connection.close();
                });

            }
```